# sphere-sphere intersection

Tags: calculus, spherical-coordinates, spheres

Let

$ S_1 : (x-1)^2 +y^2+z^2=1 $

$S_2 : x^2 +y^2 +z^2 =1$

$S_3 : (x+1)^2 +y^2 +z^2 =1 $

Find the volume of the solid inside $S_2$ and outside $S_1$ and $S_3$, using triple integrals.

I have try to express the region enclosed by two spheres in spherical coordinates, but I am stuck...
Could anyone help me please ?

Comment: I don't think spherical coordinates will be useful here, since the problem has no spherical symmetry.

Comment: This is straightforward if you use one-variable calculus to set up a volume of rotation about the $x$-axis. (It may be easier to find the volume of intersection of two of the balls, then subtract appropriately. A sketch will certainly help.)

Comment: $$\verb/Volume/ = 2 \int_0^{\frac12} \left[\pi(1-x^2) - \pi(1-(1-x)^2)\right]dx
= \cdots$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: it may be ugly, but using cylindrical coordinates about the x-axis will help. I'll work on roughing out the details.